# Expression codec (grails.views.gsp.codecs.expression) seems to be ignored in deployed war file

Tags: grails, configuration, gsp, codec, grails-4

In a fresh grails 4.0.4 application the settings of

```yaml
grails:
  views:
    gsp:
      codecs:
        expression: none
```

seem to be ignored when deployed as a war file in a Tomcat 8.5.39. (JVM 11.0.7+10-post-Ubuntu-2ubuntu218.04)

Adding this

```html
<head>
...
  <script>
    var foo = ${[a:23, b:42, c:666] as grails.converters.JSON};
  </script>
</head>
```

to the generated `grails-app/views/index.gsp` shows up as

```js
var foo = {"a":23,"b":42,"c":666};
```

when running `grails run-app` or even `grails prod run-app`(!), but is encoded as

```js
var foo = {&quot;a&quot;:23,&quot;b&quot;:42,&quot;c&quot;:666};
```

in the packaged (`grails prod war`) deployed war file.

The `build.gradle` was unmodified, except for changing

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
```

to this

```
compile("org.grails.plugins:cache") {
  exclude module:'groovy-all'
}
```

Is this a bug or am I using the codecs settings wrong? Maybe there is a plugin overwriting this settings (like here https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10722) but i cannot find any other yml files. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works like a charm in Grails 4.0.3. Seems it is broken in Grails 4.0.4 ...
Maybe the problem came with [the new Groovy Page Compiler Task](https://github.com/grails/grails-gsp/commits/master/grails-web-gsp/src/main/groovy/org/grails/web/pages/GroovyPageCompilerForkTask.groovy). The config file (aka `application.yml`) variable [here](https://github.com/grails/grails-gsp/blob/6a575c1c0e4b87752752367c9036a83dc35725ad/grails-web-gsp/src/main/groovy/org/grails/web/pages/GroovyPageCompilerForkTask.groovy#L117) is never used. But that's only an assumption after quick investigation with too little coffee ;-)

### Workaround or my preferred way (still working in Grails 4.0.4)

Some helper TagLib like this:

```
import grails.converters.JSON
class FooTagLib {
    static defaultEncodeAs = [taglib:'none']
    static namespace = "foo"
    def json = { attrs, body ->
        out << raw(attrs.data as JSON)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var foo = <foo:json data="[a:23, b:42, c:666]"/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I opened an issue in github: https://github.com/grails/grails-gsp/issues/63